# Why does R require the interleaving of values while creating a matrix?

Tags: r, matrix

```
> # create the following 2X3 matrix
> # 
> # 1 2 3
> # 4 5 6
> 
> sim = matrix(c(1,4,   2,5,   3,6), nrow = 2, ncol = 3)
> sim
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    2    3
[2,]    4    5    6
> 
> # list 2nd row of the matrix
> row2 <- sim[2,]
> row2
[1] 4 5 6
>
```

Why does R require us to interleave the values while simply creating a matrix?

Comment: Do you need `sim[2, , drop = FALSE]`

Comment: @akrun, i haven't understood.

Comment: It was not clear to me what your expected as output.  I thought you wanted to subset the row while maintaining the attributes of dim

Comment: As noted, this isn't required. But the reason it's the default is (presumably) because [that's how they're stored in memory](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/reticulate/vignettes/arrays.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default is to create matrices in a "column-major" order. If you prefer, you can use the `byrow = TRUE` argument to use row-major order instead:

```
matrix(1:6, nrow = 2, byrow = TRUE)
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]    1    2    3
# [2,]    4    5    6
```

Have a look at the help page `?matrix` for more details.